# Prefill Facebook messenger message or send out to the group

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

for one client we are trying to prepare solution, that after click on button will send from the users facebook messenger message to the facebook group with details like URL of the product etc.

Generally, I come to the product detail as a user, click on the Contact us button and, it will

1. Prefill the message with the URL to the product and some message 
   AND / OR
2. Send the message to the Facebook group that is responsible for the website the user is sending it from.

Is there any way to do this? I know how to do the opposite way of messaging, from the company to the user, but is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: Pre-filling user messages is out of the question, anywhere in the Facebook API universe - neither allowed, nor possible for most endpoints. I guess your best option is to use the [Send to Messenger Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin), and use the `ref` parameter to send along your URL.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain more how does the ref thingy work? Its not very well described in the API docs.

Comment: You specify the value when you render the plugin, and get it passed back to your bot with the `messaging_optins` webhook event.

Comment: Pre-filling message is explicitly prohibited in [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill/). Perhaps there are some hacky way to avoid their restriction but it'd be unavailable in the future.